# Large list manipulation optimization

Tags: python, python-2.7

As a follow up to [Large list generation optimization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29089435/large-list-generation-optimization/29089675) I wanted to tackle the problem the other way around.

Given a list of strings in the form of:

```
seq = ['A.p[11]','A.p[1:10]','B.p[1:2]','B.p[2]','B.p[3]','B.p[0]','A.p[0]']
```

I want a function which would return a list of "merged" element, with order preserved, like so:

```
merged = ['A.p[1:11]', 'B.p[0:3]', 'A.p[0]']
```

To achieve my goal I wrote this function:

```
def merge_seq(seq):
    ''' Merges a given sequence of strings
        Each string will consiste of word[index] or word[bottom index:top index]
        ex: given  ['A.p[11]','A.p[1:10]','B.p[1:2]','B.p[2]','B.p[3]','B.p[0]','A.p[0]']
            return ['A.p[1:11]','B.p[0:3]','A.p[0]']
    '''
    merged_list = []
    for i in seq:

        # First item? Add to list
        if not merged_list:
            merged_list.append(i)

        else:
            current = i # current item
            previous = merged_list[-1] # previous item

            # Skip if current == previous
            if current != previous:
                current = current.split('[')
                previous = previous.split('[')

                # If current word != previous, add to list
                if current[0] != previous[0]:
                    merged_list.append(i)

                else:
                    range0  = [int(x) for x in current[-1][:-1].split(':')] # current range
                    range1  = [int(x) for x in previous[-1][:-1].split(':')] # previous range

                    bottom = max(range0[0], range1[0])
                    top = min(range0[-1], range1[-1])

                    # Test if they overlap or are next to each other, if so edit last entry to reflect new range
                    if abs(bottom-top) == 1 or xrange(bottom,top+1):
                        bottom = min(range0[0], range1[0])
                        top    = max(range0[-1], range1[-1])
                        merged_list[-1] = '%s[%s]'%(previous[0],('%s:%s'%(bottom,top)))

                    # No overlap. Add to list
                    else:
                        merged_list.append(i)

    return merged_list
```

The problem with this function is that it gets very slow when dealing with large sequences.

**UPDATE**

After doing some research i stumbled upon [this answer to detect consecutive integers in a list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2361945/detecting-consecutive-integers-in-a-list). This inspired me to write a new function that leverages itertools and operator

```
from itertools import groupby
from operator import itemgetter
import re


def merge_seq2(seq):
    ''' Merges a given sequence of strings
        Each string will consiste of word[index] or word[bottom index:top index]
        ex: given   ['A.p[11]','A.p[1:10]','B.p[1:2]','B.p[2]','B.p[3]','B.p[0]','A.p[0]']
            becomes ['A.p[1:11]','B.p[0:3]','A.p[0]']
    '''
    r = re.compile(r"([0-9a-zA-Z._]+)\[(\d+)(?::(\d+))?\]")

    current = ''
    values  = set()
    result  = []
    for item in seq:
        m = r.match(item)
        name, start, end = m.group(1), int(m.group(2)), m.group(3)
        rng = xrange(start, int(end)+1) if end else (start,)

        # if this is a new item and we have values, append result
        if name != current:
            if values:
                for k, g in groupby(enumerate(sorted(values)), lambda (i,x):i-x):
                    m = map(itemgetter(1), g)
                    if len(m) == 1:
                        result.append('%s[%s]'%(current,m[0]))
                    else:
                        result.append('%s[%s:%s]'%(current,m[0],m[-1]))

            # reset 'current' name and values
            current = name
            values = set(rng)

        # else add to values  
        else:
            values.update(rng)

    # Do a last append to results and return
    if values:
        for k, g in groupby(enumerate(sorted(values)), lambda (i,x):i-x):
            m = map(itemgetter(1), g)
            if len(m) == 1:
                result.append('%s[%s]'%(current,m[0]))
            else:
                result.append('%s[%s:%s]'%(current,m[0],m[-1]))

    return result
```

Now lets compare the two functions and use [this solution to generate large lists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29089435/large-list-generation-optimization/29089675#29089675) :

```
def flatten_seq(seq):
    ''' Answered by JuniorCompressor
        https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29089435/large-list-generation-optimization/29089675#29089675
        Faster than: ['%s[%s]'%(item.split('[')[0],i) for item in seq for i in xrange(int(item.split('[')[-1][:-1].split(':')[0]),int(item.split('[')[-1][:-1].split(':')[-1])+1)]
    '''
    r = re.compile(r"([0-9a-zA-Z._]+)\[(\d+)(?::(\d+))?\]")
    result = []
    for item in seq:
        m = r.match(item)
        name, start, end = m.group(1), int(m.group(2)), m.group(3)
        rng = xrange(start, int(end)+1) if end else (start,)
        t = name + "["
        result.extend(t + str(i) + "]" for i in rng)
    return result

# Lets make 1 million entries
seq = ['A[1:500000]','B[1:500000]']
t1 = time.clock()
flat = flatten_seq(seq)
t2 = time.clock()
print '# Flattened in %s secs'%round(t2-t1, 3)

merged = merge_seq(flat)
t3 = time.clock()
print '# Old Merge %s secs'%round(t3-t2, 3)

merged = merge_seq2(flat)
t4 = time.clock()
print '# New Merge %s secs'%round(t4-t3, 3)

# Flattened in 0.265 secs
# Old Merge 6.76 secs
# New Merge 2.613 secs
```

That's ~2.5 times faster!

Only minor issue with marge_seq2 is that in some cases when given unflattened lists it can be slower than the original merge_seq function.

If anyone has suggestions to speed this up even more, I would love to hear them!

Comment: I suggest running a profiler on this. My gut feeling, though, is that you really want to build a dictionary of the form {"A.p": [1, 2, 3, 5]...}, then parse it back into a list.

Comment: @user3757614: That approach doesn't sound practical for things like `A[1:5000000]`.

Comment: One approach would be consider each string as an interval description, and then the problem becomes one of merging them together to find the longest contiguous runs.

Comment: Shouldn't the example return `merged = ['A.p[0:11]', 'B.p[0:3]']` instead?

Comment: @KlausD. I want the given order to be preserved. So working from start to finish in the example you'll see a block of sequential "B's" between "A.p[1:10]" and "A.p[0]". As such I want the final output to be ['A.p[1:11]','B.p[0:3]','A.p[0]']... if "A.p[0]" came before "B.p[1:2]" then merged would be ['A.p[0:11]', 'B.p[0:3]']

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I decided to settle with the function below leveraging my newfound knowledge of itertools. It's a few fractions of a second faster than merge_seq2 and way faster my original merge_seq function. When dealing with large unflattened ranges (ex: 0:5000000) this approach is a little slower than the original method due to the large amount of data being dropped in the set with xrange. But in my everyday use this so far works better as a general solution.

```
def merge_seq3(seq):
    ''' Merges a given sequence of strings
        Each string will consiste of word[index] or word[bottom index:top index]
        ex: given   ['A.p[11]','A.p[1:10]','B.p[1:2]','B.p[2]','B.p[3]','B.p[0]','A.p[0]']
            becomes ['A.p[1:11]','B.p[0:3]','A.p[0]']
    '''
    result = []
    for key, g in itertools.groupby(seq,lambda x:x.split('[')[0]):
        values = set()
        for item in g:
            split = item[len(key)+1:-1].split(':')
            if len(split) == 1:
                values.add(int(split[0]))
            else:
                values.update(xrange(int(split[0]),int(split[1])+1))

        if values:
            for k, g in groupby(enumerate(sorted(values)), lambda (i,x):i-x):
                m = map(itemgetter(1), g)
                if len(m) == 1:
                    result.append('%s[%s]'%(key,m[0]))
                else:
                    result.append('%s[%s:%s]'%(key,m[0],m[-1]))

    return result
```